# Importing Oracle database from dump where source dump is spread across different tablespaces

Tags: impdp

How to import an Oracle schema from a dump file into another schema in new Oracle DB, where the target schema has only USERS and TEMP table spaces where as Source schema is having data distributed in several table spaces.

I mean I need to map all the tablespaces from source schema to USERS tablespace in target schema. How can I achieve this?

I am using this but not working.

```
impdp system/oracle@comverse2 schemas=epimart directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=mart.dmp logfile=epimart.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `remap_tablespace` parameter:

```
remap_tablespace:source_tablespace_1:user,source_tablespace_2:user
```